# Django: Parse HttpResponse object for URL string data

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a Django test for a redirect that "throws" a URL string error, but I'd like to do it without brittle regexes.

```
def test_redirect_contains_error_string(self):
    response = self.client.get('/sendme/', follow=True)
    // response.redirect_chain: [('https://e.com/?error=errortype', 302)]
    url = response.redirect_chain[0][0]
    self.assertTrue(re.search('error=errortype', url))
    // Ew!
```

Is there a method to parse URLs into dict-like objects, so I can just:

```
response_obj = something(url)
self.assertEquals(response_obj.get('error'), 'errortype')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> zoo = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/foo?bar=zoo')
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(zoo.query)
{'bar': ['zoo']}
```

Comment: Thank you. That module and your example are perfect.